# Add each page of the PDF on separate pages

Tags: pdfpages

I am trying to add a 4 page PDF on 4 different pages. But it either shows one or two of the pages, and not in order either. How can I solve this?

```
\begin{figure}[!t]
\includepdf[pages={1}]{app.pdf}
\end{figure}
\clearpage


\begin{figure}[!t]
\includepdf[pages={2}]{app.pdf}
\end{figure}
\clearpage


\begin{figure}[!t]
\includepdf[pages={3}]{app.pdf}
\end{figure}
\clearpage


\begin{figure}[!t]
\includepdf[pages={4}]{app.pdf}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
```

Comment: A figure cannot hold material larger that the text block, `\includepdf` include data that are full pages. If your pdf is properly cropped, you can use `\includegraphics ` instead. Under pdflatex (and similar) it does support the `pages` option. Also use  `[tp] ` you need the p to make float pages.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pdfpages`](//ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) does not require placing the page-inclusion inside a `figure` environment. Instead, use the command `\includepdf` as-is

```
\includepdf[pages=1-4]{app.pdf}
```